# Tracking OAuth views

Tags: facebook, oauth

I was wondering if anyone has any info on tracking users who are shown our app Auth Dialog?

To be more specific, when a new user has tried to launch our application, they will be directed to a Auth Dialog Screen. 
In a FB connected site, a browser popup will appear, by way of the FbJS SDK.

Before a user decides to allow or disallow permissions, can we call a page on our servers? Some sort of pixel tracking perhaps?
I am not talking about Facebook Insights, we'd like to handle the tracking ourselves.
I cannot find much on the topic on Google or the FB Docs.

I am quite confident the answer is a solid NO, but I thought if anyone would have the answer it'd be you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to know whether it is possible to get a grip on how many are shown the authorization dialogue but then never allow your app access?

Assuming you know how many users have granted you access, the problem should be solved by you starting to track how many FB popups you fire up. I.e how many authorization processes you start. Take that number and deduct the number of successfully completed ones, that would give you the number of people who never clicked "allow".

That's the only metric I am confident you can use, but it should suffice.

It is impossible to track what happens on the authorization page itself since it is completely out of your control.

Comment: Thanks :)
I assumed this to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just make an AJAX Request to your server when the user clicks the button/link which triggers the JS SDK method call …?

Comment: As I understand it, the author wants to know whether it is possible to find out if a user has disallowed **after** having been shown the authorization dialogue. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct. 
The problem with CBroe's suggestion, is that we would only be able to track those users from the stand alone site, not from launching the application on the FB Canvas.